# Can this identity : $\sum_\limits{m=1}^d \frac{m^d(-1)^m}{m!(d-m)!}=1,\;$ be proved?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I got to this expression while working, and the identity seems to be correct. However, no matter how I tried, I could not prove it. Can you help?

$$\sum_{m=1}^d \frac{m^d(-1)^m}{m!(d-m)!}=1$$

$$d=2n, n\in \Bbb N$$

Comment: Hi amWhy, I looked at your profile. You seem to be a top 0.08% user, probably very knowledgeable, and even post the **Be Nice** message, with specifics for new comers. I fail to see how this sits with your response above. Even if that's what you think, you could have said it less aggressively. This is my first experience here, and was merely trying to follow the rules, which said "be specific and no chit chat"

Comment: In any case, this was no homework, I am not a student, and no mathematician. I have 2 years of Physics studying in University in my past, and here I was simply playing with some series (at my free time and just out of curiousity), found something interesting and tried to prove it. I almost made it, and at the final stages got to this identity that I did not manage to prove, and looked for help online. If you are interested, I can expand on all that.

Comment: G.Berger: It does seem my message came off sounding "nasty"; I deleted my comment. Just before my comment to you,  I dealt with a number of posts from users who had created another account, thus becoming "new users", after their previous accounts have bee suspended or blocked from asking questions.  That's not an excuse. And my comment was less than "nice".

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. Seriously. All good now, let's focus on Math :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of a standard explicit formula for the Stirling numbers of the second kind,

$${d\brace k}=\frac1{k!}\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^{k-m}\binom{k}mm^d\;.\tag{1}$$

Replace $k$ by $d$ in $(1)$ to get

$$\frac1{d!}\sum_{m=0}^d(-1)^{d-m}\binom{d}mm^d={d\brace d}\;,$$

then use the fact that $d$ is even and that ${d\brace d}$ is the number of partitions of $[d]$ into $d$ parts, which is of course $1$.

The formula

$$k!{d\brace k}=\sum_{k=0}^k(-1)^{k-m}\binom{k}mm^d$$

can easily be derived by an inclusion-exclusion argument counting permutations of $[d]$.

Comment: Thank you Brian, this was very helpful, and got me what I needed. First I hear of the Stirling numbers, so I read a little about them. Interesting.

Comment: @G.Berger: You’re welcome; glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I gave this exercise to a student just yesterday : let $d$ be an integer greater than $2$. Consider function $f:x\mapsto (1-e^x)^d$. By computing an asymptotic development of $f$ around $0$ to the precision $d$ *by two different means*, find the values of the sums 
$$\sum_{m=0}^d \binom dm(-1)^m m^l\text{ for }0\le k\le d$$
First way is just saying 
$$f(x)=(-x+o(x))^d=(-1)^dx^d+o(x^d)$$
Second way is using binomial formula :
\begin{align}f(x)&=\sum_{m=0}^d \binom dm (-1)^m e^{mx} \\ 
    &= \sum_{m=0}^d \binom dm (-1)^m \left(\sum_{k=0}^d \frac{m^kx^k}{k!}\right) \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^d \frac{x^k}{k!} \left(\sum_{m=0}^d \binom dm (-1)^m m^k\right)
\end{align}
Now compare both developments.

Comment: Thanks for that Nicolas. Actually, I am not sure I got it all, perhaps this was a bit over my current level. At any case, looking at the Stirling numbers of second kind formula, I got what I needed. Thanks again.